# Can i set locale through Resources.resx in VS Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, locale

Resources.resx has references to the culture etc. Is it possible to set the default locale in English in the resources.resx.

I tried setting cultureinfo in the Resources.Designer.cs file. but it does let me. Is there any other way to set and will that enable my application to list all output in english?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default locale in AssemblyInfo.cs using the NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute.

E.g

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the culture of the current thread using

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```